# How to login to a JSP webpage using Android?

Tags: javascript, android, jsp, authentication

This is the site I would need logging in to:

My goal is to incorporate some elements of a website into an app, by fetching the required data. Unfortunately, the webpage requires a login. how do i login to the webpage from the app itself so that the user logs in to the site like he would on a native app and use the session to fetch the required data?
I though of implementing custom CSS, but is there any other/better way of doing this? JS perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically the same way, you would have done it, had you tried to contact gmail via your app. As it presently stands, you can use the same procedure for any website. Let's see how we can do it for Gmail :

Now "Clicking" is basically sending a request to a server and displaying the return in formations .

1/ find out what url to call for that request (if it is a web page, see firebug for example)

2/ find out what the parameters are, find out if the method is GET or POST

3/ reproduce pro grammatically.

4/ a "login" phase probably implies the usage of a cookie, which the server gives you and that you must send back afterward for each request.

Once you receive the response, you'll want to check that

```
  response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() < 400
```

It will tell you that login was successful. (2xx are success, 3xx are moved and such. 4xx are errors in the request, 5xx are server side errors ; Gmail responds 302 to login to suggest redirection to inbox). Then, you'll notice that there is a particular header in the response "Set-Cookie" that contains the cookie you want for further connections so :

```
  String cookie = response.getFistHeader("Set-Cookie");
```

Then, you should be able to call the request to get the contacts :

```
HttpGet getContacts = new HttpGet(GMAIL_CONTACTS);
getContacts.setHeader("Cookie", cookie);
response = httpClient.execute(getContacts);
InputStream ins = response.getEntity().getContent();
```

So all in all, the code stands at something like this :

```
    String GMAIL_CONTACTS = "https://mail.google.com/mail/?shva=1#contacts";
    String GMAIL_LOGIN = "https://mail.google.com";

    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(GMAIL_LOGIN);

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email", MY_ACC));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Passwd", MY_PASS));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("signIn", "Sign In"));

    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request 
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    Log.d(TAG, "response stat code " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() < 400) {

    String cookie = response.getFirstHeader("Set-Cookie")
    .getValue();
    Log.d(TAG, "cookie: " + cookie);

    // get the contacts page 
    HttpGet getContacts = new HttpGet(GMAIL_CONTACTS);
    getContacts.setHeader("Cookie", cookie);
    response = httpClient.execute(getContacts);

    InputStream ins = response.getEntity().getContent();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    ins));
```

I don't see any reason, why you can't apply the same in your case. The process is all too similar .

Answer (score 0):

You can use Webview to load the page using webview.loadUrl(urlString); 
Which will work same as it work on desktop , but still you will have to take care of the resolution of the page(i.e. Height/Width of the UI Component).

Hope it helps, Let me know if you need more help