# Binding a web page's element to an Android App

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, web

There is a website which has a login screen, and when the submit is hit, it goes to a new page and logs in the user.

Here's a screenshot :[image: Airtel]

Now, Suppose I have a similar login screen in my android app, like this :

[image: Login UI]

Now, Is there a way to link both of them, so that, when I hit login in the android app, it actually registers a submit at that website and logs in the user, and obviously, then again, binding the next webpage that shows up after logging in. How dlink the urlfrom the webpage to the js and elements in an android app?

I know there has to be javascript, but how?

Comment: What does 'binding the next webpage' mean? Are you trying to so something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294800/how-to-login-to-a-jsp-webpage-using-android which would then be followed by HTML scraping?

Comment: Yes. Exactly the same thing. It's like I have to create a native app version of a website, using js and html and css, and with proper UI ( an not just  webview sort of thing) and hence replicate the same process. How can I achieve this? How do I find out the url's and then use HTTP and Js andstuff to solve it?

Comment: does the site has an api?

Comment: No. It doesnt have an API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While login we sends the form data from Android application to the Server-side page (JSP, Servlet,ASP or PHP), then those page will compile the required operation for login validation using any database , then it returns “1” if the login is valid else return “0”.

Hence you have to find out all the parameters that are working around once you click the login or register in that website.Also login page may contain cookies and other temp storage that will be required at each login.Also you need to find the methods used.

So **understanding the webpage configurations ,parameters and functionality** will help you achieve using android tools like webview(just a tool,not logic).

First make a detailed study on all the required parameters and functionality of the webpage then get started with the app.

Below is a list of reference links that may help you to tackle the issue :

[Refer 1](https://wowjava.wordpress.com/2011/01/16/login-application-for-android/),
[Refer 2](http://www.javatpoint.com/login-form-in-jsp),
[Refer 3](http://javaknowledge.info/login-and-registration-example-in-jsp-with-session/),
[Refer 4](http://javatechig.com/java/struts/creating-login-application-using-struts2),
[Refer 5](http://webdesignergeeks.com/mobile/android/android-login-authentication-with-remote-db/)

Comment: Thanks. I'll look to find out those parameters, and then go further.

Answer (score 4):

Have you Checked this : http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

and this : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/392603/Android-addJavaScriptInterface

Comment: I have but cannot understand it. If you could describe it with an example?

Answer (score 1):

You can also see this site to solve ur probelm ...
[image]

https://wowjava.wordpress.com/2011/01/16/login-application-for-android/

or

http://webdesignergeeks.com/mobile/android/android-login-authentication-with-remote-db/